# Trouble installing cx_Oracle using pip

Tags: python, oracle, pip, cx-oracle

I am trying to install `cx_Oracle` using pip but I keep getting this output in console.

```
(test_env1)[ django@hostname ~ ] $ pip install cx_Oracle
Collecting cx_Oracle
  Using cached cx_Oracle-5.3.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: cx-Oracle
  Running setup.py install for cx-Oracle ... error
    Complete output from command /opt/svcacct/django/test_env1/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4525wz/cx-Oracle/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BoJI2V-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/svcacct/django/test_env1/include/site/python2.7/cx-Oracle:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'cx_Oracle' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7-11g
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7-11g/src
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/app/oracle/instantclient_11_1/sdk/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/cx_Oracle.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7-11g/src/cx_Oracle.o -DBUILD_VERSION=5.3
    src/cx_Oracle.c:28:2: error: #error Oracle 11.2 or later client libraries are required for building
     #error Oracle 11.2 or later client libraries are required for building
      ^
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/opt/svcacct/django/test_env1/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4525wz/cx-Oracle/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-BoJI2V-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/svcacct/django/test_env1/include/site/python2.7/cx-Oracle" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4525wz/cx-Oracle/
```

I have my oracle install in my env variables.

Comment: you need install oracle client from oracle website and then install cx_Oracle

Comment: What environment variables have you set?

Comment: I have `export ORACLE_HOME=/app/oracle/instantclient_11_1/` in my .bashrc profile

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that an Oracle Client has been installed on your machine. The easiest is the Oracle Instant Client which you can get from here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

Follow the instructions at the bottom of the page. Make sure you have installed the "Basic" or "Basic Light" package as well as the "SDK" package. The "SDK" package is only required for building cx_Oracle.